# regex PHP: finding missing semicolon in query db2

Tags: php, sql, regex, db2

I want to write regex PHP code to find missing semicolon in a query.
Queries are along with the PHP codes. For a better look it has used so many newlines and prentices.
Problem is that between these codes how to find out exactly a missing ;
look at it as a challenge not using other tools. RegEx in PHP

here is my try but it doesn't work.

```
regex="/\b(delete|insert|trancinate)\b(.*\n*(^;))*;?/gi"
prep_find_all(regex,$query,$missings);
```

like this one in the code `;` this is the missing semicolon.
my idea for functional code is that check if a new statement stated and doesn't finish with `;` 
otherwise, we can check at the end of all line for `;` but not necessarily need semicolon for all endings.

```
?php

$database = 'SAMPLE';
$user = 'db2inst1';
$password = 'ibmdb2';
$hostname = 'localhost';
$port = 50000;

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
  "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    } else {
    echo "Connection failed.";
}
$query = "
delete from L3_STAMM.L3_STAMM_ATTRIBUT ;
-- comment bla
DELETE FROM ETL.ETL_OPERATOR_TABELLE WHERE TABELLE IN 
(
 'L4_GENERELLE_STAMMDATEN'
,'L4_AVAL'
,'L4_DARLEHEN_FAZILITAET'
,'L4_IOPC_DARL_CASHFLOW'
)**;*
";
$exect = db2_exec($conn, $query);
if ($exect){echo "success.\n";}
db2_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Why? This seems like a bad idea on so many levels.

Comment: I am coding inside a limited system, we cannot use an IDE here. what do you mean by so many levels?

Comment: First of all, if you miss a semi-colon you'll find out at runtime and can fix. Second, you really should not try to run multiple SQL statements in one call because it couples the calls closely. It makes it harder to identify when you have an issue. Third, this style of coding breeds bad coding habits. Finally, you don't need an IDE, just a text editor that does syntax highlighting.

Comment: First, thanks for correcting my question, Then, also thanks for your tips Jay.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem to me.  Your usage of `(^;)` says "capture the semicolon at the start of the string" -- it is basically nonsense in the context of your logic.  I don't want to touch this question with a 10-foot pole because no matter how well I craft the regular expression, I will very easily be able to create an input string that would break my pattern.  I recommend that you completely rethink this aspect of your project.